# Does Count (*) skew desired results when performing additional join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My query works fine; however, I need to join another dataset to my query, and I expect that the `count(f.*)` will break.

Here's the query I start with:

```
SELECT
       MIN(received_date) AS FirstVisit
     , patient_id         AS PatientID
INTO #LookupTable
FROM F_ACCESSION_DAILY

SELECT 
       f.doctor           AS Doctor
     , COUNT(f.*)         AS CountNewPatients
     , MONTH(firstvisit)  AS Month
     , YEAR(firstvisit)   AS Year
FROM F_ACCESSION_DAILY f 
INNER JOIN #LookupTable l ON f.received_date = l.FirstVisit 
                         AND f.patient_id = l.PatientID
GROUP BY f.doctor
       , MONTH(firstvisit)
       , YEAR(firstvisit)

DROP TABLE #LookupTable
```

I would like to Join the above query on another table.

The question is ****will my `count(f.*)` stay the same or will it change because I've added a new dataset?****

****How do I make sure that the `count(f.*)` will remain the same?**

Thank you so much for your guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will my `count(f.*)` stay the same or will it change because I've added a new dataset?*

`COUNT(*)` counts rows. If you join another table and the number of rows increases, the result of `COUNT(*)` will increase.

> How do I make sure that the `count(f.*)` will remain the same?

Use `COUNT (DISTINCT f.Id)`.

Answer (score 1):

If there's exactly a 1 row per patient_id in the new table (and you're doing an INNER JOIN) then the count won't change.  Otherwise, it will.

You could use an OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ....) instead of a JOIN to guarantee that the count won't change.

By the way, it looks like you're missing a GROUP BY patient_id in your first SELECT.

Comment: cool!! can you show me more about how i can do outer apply instead of join, i never knew this. can you show me a source please?

Comment: I don't know what your other table looks like, and I'm not sure you only want one row from it per patient_id, but if so, I presume you want something like "OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM MyTable t WHERE t.patient_id = f.patient_id)" maybe with an order by to choose which row to get in case there's more than one.

Answer (score 1):

Joins do not "skew" the `COUNT(*)`.  The count does exactly what it is advertised to do.  The problem is that you may be multiplying the number of rows, without really realizing it.

One way to solve the problem is to do the aggregations at the appropriate level.  Sometimes, you have to do it this way -- for instance, when SUMs and AVGs are involved.

For the count, though, you can replace it with:

```
count(distinct AccessionDailyID)
```

Even if the rows gets multiplied, then this will work to get your count.  By the way, this assumes thatyour table has a unique id for each row.

By the way, you may want to be sure thatyou use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` to be sure that you don't lose any rows in the joining process.